# Trouble splitting a String with Python

Tags: python, parsing, split, text-processing

I'm desperatly trying to split a string using Python but the text file I need to parse is a little bit tricky:

- The text file is a comma separated data file

I did the following:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("sample.txt"):
data = line.strip().split(',')
pass
```

This actually should make the job right ?

Ok now the tricky part: I have some field that contains comma inside like the one below:

```
"(CONTRACTS OF 5,000 BUSHELS)"
```

using my code, the script also split this field in 2.

How can I ask python to use comma as a delimiter but not when they are enclosed by "" ?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Crak

Comment: Why do you have a `pass` in your code example?

Comment: It seems that the solution was in the question: `The text file is a comma separated data file.` I was confused because of the file extension which was a `.txt`... One day lost for almost nothing :) Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Your data is in a pretty common format -- Comma Separated Values (CSV).  Instead of writing yet another parser, consider using the built-in [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Seems like good advice, but an example of how the csv module would be used in this case would really improve this answer.

Comment: There are plenty of examples in the official documentation, I don't think copying one of those here makes a difference.

Comment: Maybe it's because I've never used a csv library that after several minutes of reading the docs left me confused. You are right, you have provided what is necessary. But it would have made a difference for me, if it were my problem.

Comment: @FarmBoy: There are hundreds of questions about CSV already on Stack Overflow.  Please search for Python and CSV. There's no point in repeating any of those answers on this question.

Comment: @FarmBoy: Please click on the link to the `csv` module in my answer and scroll down a couple of lines to the first green box for a very straight-forward example. And please, be polite, I totally agree with @S.Lott's comment.

Answer (score 5):

CSV files should be handled with [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 4):

you can use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module

```
import csv

with open('sample.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # each row is a list of items,
        # corresponding to each row in your file,
        # including commas for quoted items
```

Comment: I'd upvote this answer, if it contained something meaningful where the comment is.

Comment: the question didn't specify what he is doing with it

Comment: He is splitting on commas, but not splitting on commas within quotations.